# set up a test URL( drupal website) in cpanel

Tags: web, drupal-7, cpanel

I want to create a test url to see how my drupal 7 website that I have developed in my local box looks like in the host that will eventually shows the website . this website will replace the old website already set up in cpanel. I do not want to touch the old website that is public to all in the web yet, since I want to do more testing with the new website while putting it on cpanel and also share it with only one person so I can get feedback for the website.

is there a way to set up a test website in drupal for testing and sharing with one person  without impacting the public website (old website that will be eventually replaced).

I am in a rush, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create sub-domain from cpanel like subdomain.yourDomain.com and can upload your content in subdomain and also can share credential for subdomain with 2nd person.

The second option is you can create FTP account from cpanel and can upload content in ftp user and also can give access to another person because the ftp user or subdomain user will not able to see file of your domain.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So can I do this without affecting the public website that all its files are in public_html folder? I can transfer the new website files into the sub domain folder (not the public_html folder) and will be able to share the website with someone else? even if the new files for the new website are not in public_html folder?

Comment: When you will create subdomain from cpanel, by-default it create its home directory in public_html of your main domain. For example your domain mysite.com and you want to create subdomain as test.mysite.com then it will create test folder in public_html of mysite. But you can change it manually when you will create subdomain just edit the document root path of subdomain as /home/user/public_html/test to /home/user/test. Now with default user you can check both public_html and test separately, but with this procedure the 2nd member also can check public_html contents.

Comment: Thank you , I was able to finally set up the test site without impacting the current production site.